# How to handle git pull error in untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge

Tags: git, github

When I tried `git pull` I suffered following errors.

As I am beginner I couldn't understand what happened.

My question is

①What is the cause of this error.

②Why the following command recommended.

```
  git config pull.rebase false  # merge (the default strategy)
  git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
  git config pull.ff only       # fast-forward only
```

③ Why the following happened. why the files are overwritten by merge ?

`error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:`

The whole messages is following.

If someone has opinion, please let me know Thanks!

```
$ git pull
warning: Pulling without specifying how to reconcile divergent branches is
discouraged. You can squelch this message by running one of the following
commands sometime before your next pull:

  git config pull.rebase false  # merge (the default strategy)
  git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
  git config pull.ff only       # fast-forward only

You can replace "git config" with "git config --global" to set a default
preference for all repositories. You can also pass --rebase, --no-rebase,
or --ff-only on the command line to override the configured default per
invocation.

remote: Enumerating objects: 27, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (27/27), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Total 18 (delta 13), reused 17 (delta 12), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (18/18), 2.34 KiB | 50.00 KiB/s, done.
From https://github.com/test/app
   3f7d8e0..e75a68e  attendances-api#8           -> origin/attendances-api#8
 * [new branch]      attendances-register-api#12 -> origin/attendances-register-api#12
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
        api/src/notices/dto/notice.dto.ts
        api/src/notices/notice.service.spec.ts
        api/src/notices/notice.service.ts
        api/src/notices/notices.controller.spec.ts
        api/src/notices/notices.controller.ts
        api/src/notices/notices.module.ts
        api/src/repositories/notices.repository.ts
Please move or remove them before you merge.
Aborting
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate things here, so let's go over them one at a time.

First, the message you're getting in #2 is a notification that Git can do many different things when you pull.  By default, if the branches have diverged, it does a merge.  This has been the behavior for a long time, but if you're pulling in changes from a main branch that you share with a lot of people, then the right strategy is to do a fast-forward only.  That's because you probably did not want to commit on the main branch, but instead on a feature branch, and instead of creating a merge commit that further causes your branch to diverge, the better thing to do is fail and let you fix your branch.

This is just a warning, though, and it tells you what you can do to change the behavior.  You can run one of those command to silence the command, but ultimately this message is unrelated to the problem you're having.  If you're working on a project with other people and aren't expecting to be doing work directly on the main branch, then choosing the fast-forward only option is probably best.

The other issue, which you're seeing in #1 and #3, is that somewhere in your working tree, there are files that are currently untracked.  However, when you're pulling, the new commit that Git wants to check out has those files tracked.  In general, Git doesn't want to overwrite untracked files in the working tree because sometimes they're important to the user, and the user would be unhappy if they were overwritten or deleted.

However, Git can't perform this checkout with those untracked files in place.  If those files aren't valuable to you, or you want to overwrite them with the copy from the version you're pulling, just delete them.  Otherwise, if you want to keep your versions, move them somewhere else out of the way.