# The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge (keep image)

Tags: git

While trying to pull I get the following error. I want to keep this image when I pull. How could I do that?

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    wp-content/themes/something/assets/img/image.png
Please move or remove them before you merge.
```

Comment: Just do what the message says! Move the image file out of the working tree and proceed. Deal with the consequences after the pull.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle git pull error in untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64278764/how-to-handle-git-pull-error-in-untracked-working-tree-files-would-be-overwritte)

Answer (score 0):

The upstream copy has a new file which is the same as yours!

You can either

- remove the file
- rename the file
- commit the file and then merge from upstream, picking one of them to keep

Answer (score 0):

Before the change, run:

```
git stash
```

Then,

```
git merge ...
```

Then,

```
git stash pop
```

Comment: You need to add untracked files before stashing them, but this may be a better option too!